# Ordering a range of values within a list where property values are the same

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I have range values in a list that I want to order in a descending by date, where property values are the same.

I cannot just sort everything as it is sorted by an Id first ThenBy date.

So my first step is as follow

```
 activites = activites.OrderByDescending(a => a.StageId).ThenBy(d => DateTime.Parse(d.InteractionDate)).ToList();
```

Problem is where the id's are the same (see below)

- 8 Scheduled Call - June 12, 2018
- 7 Activation - June 4, 2018
- 7 Activation - June 5, 2018
- 7 Activation - June 6, 2018
- 6 Mail - June 1, 2018

and I want it sorted like this.

- 8 Scheduled Call - June 12, 2018
- 7 Activation - June 6, 2018
- 7 Activation - June 5, 2018
- 7 Activation - June 4, 2018
- 6 Mail - June 1, 2018

I tried this as the next step which was not successful. The field value (StageName) can change and doesn't always stay the same.

```
var stages = activities.Select(s => s.StageName).ToList();
        foreach(var s in stages)
        {
            activities.Where(a => a.StageName== s).OrderByDescending(a => DateTime.Parse(a.InteractionDate)).ToList();               
        }
        return activities;
```

In the code, 'stages' represent Scheduled Call, Activation etc.

Comment: why not change ur string such that 6 Mail - June 1, 2018 can be written as *01062018:6 Mail* like that, here 01 represent 1st date, 06 represent June and 2018 the year and then sort it as usual on starting on their numbers

Comment: Is your problem that you just need the `ThenBy` descending, too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
activites = activites
    .OrderByDescending(a => a.StageId)
    .ThenByDescending(d => DateTime.Parse(d.InteractionDate)).ToList();
```